# How to achieve the same background image effect made in other stack communities?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I see those cool background in other stack communities like [World building stack exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and I decide I wanna make one like this. So first I tried to check what technique is used, Opened the inspect tool in Chrome to see how stack achieved this, and I only got more confused. At first I really thought that the only thing I can achieve this is to make a div and add a background-image property with css and that's it, but apparently that's not how it works. I could not really notice the technique used by just inspecting the elements as there was a lot and I was overwhelmed and got confused.

I also tried dragging some of the images in the background, but couldn't, why is that?

I wanna know the technique used by stack to make this background and what are the upsides for the their technique?, cause I think an image that size would take too long to load.

**One more Question**

if you know other tricks/ techniques concerning big size images in the background, I would love to know them.

Comment: Use CSS's background-image on the body?

Comment: Ok, that's just it? The image is too big, is there any trick stack uses to make the image load faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Check this codepen link http://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/GjEGvo?editors=1100 I just try to create same background. I hope It will help you to understand this better way.

Also see below the whole code:

```css
  body {
     background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/figures.png?v=9929c8f67b27') no-repeat,url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-body-texture.png?v=1076ddfe073d') repeat,url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-land.svg?v=dfaf33c88b06') no-repeat;
     background-position: left 500px, center, center, center 204px;
     background-size: 20%, auto, 100%;
     background-attachment:scroll;
 }

.container {
     background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/rift-top.svg?v=11805d608ac1),url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-header.jpg?v=88701e2ba1ac),url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-header-tile.png?v=128b1e116433);
     background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-x;
     background-position: center bottom,center top,center top;
  background-size: 103%,2000px,auto;
       min-height: 900px;
        }

#footer {
    background: #182332;
    background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/rift-bottom.svg?v=4d5835e6daff') center top no-repeat,url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-footer-grid.png?v=830466e4b56d') center bottom repeat-x,url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/worldbuilding/img/bg-stars.png?v=e6409fe22c58') center bottom repeat-x,linear-gradient(135deg, #182332 0, #235843 100%);
    background-size: 103%,auto,auto;
       background-attachment: scroll,scroll,scroll;
       min-height: 580px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>worldbuilding.stackexchange.com - Background</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```